# How to load the images in ActiveReport from ASP.NET on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, activereports

I have an ActiveReports report in ASP.NET WebSite. This report contains some images on a physical path on Server. 
The images path is:

```
\\{Server IP}\Produktion\Img\Art\
```

I added this path as VirtualPath in Debug and on IIS. The report is rendered good with images in Debug but make an error on IIS.
Error text in IIS on report rendering is:

```
Error: \\{Server IP}\Produktion\Img\Art\img01.png
```

Physically this image is there.

Can anybody write me how to load right images on IIS (not debug) to can rendering the report.

Comment: Are images hosted on network folder "\\{Server IP}\Produktion\Img\Art\"? When you deploy website on IIS, ensure that ApplicationPool user has read permissions on network folder.

Comment: I added other user in ApplicationPool and now works good (So when I added this VirtualPath to WebSite I had set an user that has rights to this path, now I had set the same user in ApplicationPool -> Identity). Thank you very much. Please add you comment as Answer and tomorrow I will close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy website on IIS, ensure that Application pool user has read permissions on network folder `\\{Server IP}\Produktion\Img\Art\`

Comment: @wertyk That should be exactly what the full error page told you, so next time you should dig into the whole error page, line by line.